# Removing quotes from python set of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I am creating an empty set and adding multiple strings to it using the `.add()` function. When I print out my set, it has this format:

```
{'abc', 'def', 'ghi'}
```

Is there a way in Python 3 to remove the quotes that surround each string so the set would return

```
{abc, def, ghi}
```

Comment: Sure, but you need to code it yourself. Why do you think you need this though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Python containers, including sets, use `repr()` to show their contents; this is meant to be a *debugging aid*, a developers representation, not something to give to end users.

As such, you'll need to manually format your strings if you want to show the contents without using `repr()`. For example:

```
def set_representation(s):
    return '{{{}}}'.format(', '.join(map(str, s)))
```

maps values to `str()` before joining them with commas and surrounding the result with `{...}` braces.

This produces:

```
>>> s = {'abc', 'def', 'ghi'}
>>> print(set_representation(s))
{def, ghi, abc}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a loop go through all items in the data structure and print each one exactly as you wish. You can also add them to a string to and print that.